# how to set prettier unique for different languages in vscode settings.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using `prettier` extension in `vscode` to format both `html` and `md` files, it is beautiful to set `tabwidth = 4` in `html` files, but ugly in `md`.
I set `prettier.tabWidth` in vscode `settings.json`

```
"prettier.tabWidth": 4
```

But this setting will take effect for all languages. Is there a method that can set the `prettier` in `settings.json` and only sets the indentation of `HTML` files without affecting the indentation of `MD` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, prettier doesn't work that way in settings.json or even with a global rc file. At this point I have a directory with presets for prettier which I copy/paste to my package.json per project within vscode.

```
package.json(per project):

"prettier": {
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```